# How to solve Is not a function error for req.functions in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am getting the following error for my code.
**TypeError: req.user.getCart is not a function**
May I know why it is happening? I just tried with other common solutions but it didn't work well.
App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const body_parser = require('body-parser');
const PNFController = require('./controllers/error');

const User = require('./models/user');
const mongoConnect = require('./util/databases').mongoConnect;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    User
        .findById('5e956a9c8a1df43870dca832')
        .then(user => {
            req.user = new User(user.name, user.email, user.cart, user._id);
            next();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);
app.use(PNFController.pnf);

mongoConnect(() => {
    app.listen(3000);
});
```

Controller(Shop.js)

```
exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('control1');
    req.user.getCart()
        .then(products => {
            res.render('shop/cart', {
                path: '/cart',
                pageTitle: 'Cart',
                products: products
                //total: cart.totalPrice
            });
        })
        .catch(err =>
            console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Any chance `User.findById` is not returning anything?

Comment: @CastroRoy I solved the problem, when I removed static keyword in the getCart function in model. May I know what is the problem of using static keyword inside the function in a constructor class

Answer (score 1):

double check if the method getCart is static, if so remove the static keyword in front of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).